# iOS NSURL String

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I am trying to place strings inside my NSURL, I have tried most suggestions but all seem to fail, i'm trying to find a easy way to do it instead of having to use some long request with long code. I'm wondering is there anything small here i'm forgetting?

```
NSString *lat = @"53.350628";
NSString *lng = @"-6.254997";
NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/jsontest.php?lat=%@&lng=%@&max=5", lat, lng];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];
```

Thanks,

Curtis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+[NSURL URLWithStirng:]` does not take a format string and a variable argument list. It just takes a string, so you should use something like `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` first before passing it to `URLWithString`, like this:

```
NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/jsontest.php?lat=%@&lng=%@&max=5", lat, lng]];
```

Comment: Don't forget to [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]

Answer (score 0):

Format the string, than add that to the NSURL

```
NSString *lat = @"53.350628";
NSString *lng = @"-6.254997";

//Format String
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/jsontest.php?lat=%@&lng=%@&max=5", lat, lng];

NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];
```